# Excel data compare and change

Tags: database, excel, compare, match, calculated-columns

I'll try to stay clear. So the problem is I want to change some data based on the cells value.
Let say the column A is the price, column B is the base value to compar with (like item001,item002), column C is the value for comparing (item001,item002,etc.) with the NEW price in column D. I would like to find the same value in column B and C, and depending if there is a match,to change the value in right row of column A to value in column D. Was it clear enough? Basicly I have 4 columns, 2 times the codes and the prices of the codes. I want Excel to find the same codes and change the price of the old to the new one. The first two columns with price and codes are much longer then the other 2 columns with new price and the data to compare won't be in the same row for sure.

Probably there is no simple solution, but would help my work a lot. I would appreciate if someone can tell which functions should I use in combination.

Sorry for being a noob, have to start learning from somewhere.

Best regards,
Endre Kalmar

Comment: in col E, you can write an IF formula to check if B=C and then output the value in Col E based on your condition. Once done, copy paste the values in Col A?

Comment: It is not a good solution as the B≠C in most of the cases,because there are different datasources,as in 1 row for ex. 1,2,3,4 and the other for ex. 1,5,7,9. In this case only 1=1 the others are false and nothing will happen. Definitely have to use vlookup function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, ...

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
  -------------------------
1 |price| ID  |  ID |price|
```

This is the situation you got?

In column E, put

```
VLOOKUP(B1; C:D; 2; FALSE)
```

Depending on your regional settings, the `;` might be replaced with a `,`

This will give you the price in column D when the value in column B can be found in column C
If it cannot be found, you get an `#N/A` error

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I'll try it and post the result.

Comment: Very useful tipp, thanks Michaël. Can more formula be implemented in this one? Like if there is no match,then the old data is kept? And what do You think where should I start learning these stuff? Thanks again.

Comment: in column F, put `IF(ISERROR(E1);A1;E1)`
I usually use `techonthenet.com` to get more info about excel formula's and see some examples.  But in general, the internet is your friend ;)